# Vue-router route not being rendered when going back to parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, quasar-framework

I have a setup in the router where the parent is a page and the child is a modal. When the child is dismissed I push the parent route using:

```
this.$router.push({
 name: 'Parent',
 params: {
  param1,
  param2,
 },
});
```

The setup of the router looks like this

```
{
    path: '/:param1/:param2',
    component: () => import('pages/Parent'),
    name: 'Parent',
    props: true,
    children: [
      {
        path: ':childParam',
        component: () => import('pages/Child'),
        name: 'Child',
        props: true,
        meta: {
          showModal: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

But when the modal gets dismissed and the parent route gets pushed nothing gets rendered while you can clearly see the parent page being rendered behind the modal while the modal is visible. At the instant when the modal is dismissed the parent page is gone as well...

Comment: Are you using router-view into the parent's template? You should be using this tag instead of pushing back/forward

Comment: I am using router view inside the parent yes, but instead of using router.back() which in case of deep linking won't go back to parent I have to use push...

Comment: Okay understood, are you seeing any error in the console? You might won't be able to use push in this case because you can't push to the same route, so you might prefer using router.replace instead. But you can stick to the $router.go(-1) option checking if there is any history to go back first. Using this: ```window.history.length > 2```

Comment: But as it is a modal I don't know if there will be the case where you move directly to the modal route, the user should be going always to the parent first

Comment: I think the issue has to do with caching, I am caching the parent route